# Enable sites in localhost doesn't work

Tags: apache2, localhost

I'm trying to enable an other site in my localhost without success. I already have this file like /etc/apache2/sites-avaiable/itransformer.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName itransformer
  DocumentRoot /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer/web
    <Directory /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer/web/>
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All               
                    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and it works right. But when I try to add a site, it doesn't work.
I copy the same file:

```
$ sudo cp itransformer.conf itransformer-2.0.conf
```

And modify the file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName itransformer-2.0
  DocumentRoot /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/web
    <Directory /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/web/>
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All               
                    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, I eneble the site:

```
$ sudo a2ensite itransformer-2.0.conf
```

And restart the server:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

And it should work when I put itransformer-2.0 in the browser, but does nothing.

Comment: First of all using dot in host names should work but generally speaking is rather bad idea. Also do you have entry for itransformer-2 in /etc/hosts?

Comment: All right! Thanks. I had forgot it. Now I have the next error: Warning: require(/home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 42

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 42

Comment: Don't ask me about php, but are you sure that path for /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/functio‌​ns.php is correct?

Comment: Seems that, for some reason, when I push my repository to bitbucket, the files inside each vendor directory are not been copied. It would seem that is caused because of the .gitignore file, but not.

Comment: Nothing to commit. This is what I can see at one vendor directory form bitbucket repository: "assetic → 0e18168c45df [0e18168c45df]". Why cannot see the files and folders inside?

Comment: I'll better ask this on a new question. Thanks a lot!